# React Stateless Function Components using Flow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

First time using Flow and Im still trying to take it all in.
Since Header is a function does it need a return type?

Also regarding the Props, since logout and handleModalOpen do not take in any arguments is `() => void` valid syntax or should this be changed?

I feel like Im getting the hang of Flow but I would like to make sure before I make any major mistakes.

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

type Props = {
  logout: () => void,
  handleModalOpen: () => void,
  isAuth: boolean,
}

const Header = (props: Props) => (
  <Navbar inverse fluid collapseOnSelect>
    <Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <Link to={props.isAuth ? '/dashboard' : '/'}>My Saved Recipes</Link>
      </Navbar.Brand>
      {props.isAuth && (
        <Navbar.Toggle />
      )}
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavItem eventKey={1} onClick={props.handleModalOpen}>
          + Add Recipe
        </NavItem>
        {/* <LinkContainer to="/account">
          <NavItem eventKey={2}>
            Account
          </NavItem>
        </LinkContainer> */}
        <NavItem eventKey={3} onClick={props.logout}>
          Logout
        </NavItem>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to annotate the return type, but if you want to type `Header`, I would probably just do it like so:

```
const Header: React$ComponentType<Props> = props => /* ...etc */
```

It will add the prop requirements.

As far as your `props`, you should type those functions for what you're expecting. If you are expecting a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing, you've got it nailed. If you want it to potentially, take an event, then you'll probably want your `props` to accept that.

Comment: So when using Flow with React I dont have to add return types for stateless functional components? Is it good practice to?

Comment: If you type the actual component, the return type is already set. If you look at the definition for [`StatelessFunctionalComponent`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.63.1/lib/react.js#L121) (which `ComponentType` uses), you can see that the return type is already set.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to return a react element check here for more information https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/9e2651b7dd0c632d42dd740dc4b9be0700371e89/lib/react.js